# ag-grid buttonrenderer non-static label for each button

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying to immplement a buttonrenderer inside angular ag-grid

so i have a columndefs defined. The problem is the label of button is static and cannot be changed. Hence all buttons have same label, but i want to give the cell content value ('field from columndefs') as label to the button

Is that possible?
If yes any ideas how?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-button-renderer?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: if I understand you properly, you want show the label as the data come from the server (field value)..?

Comment: yes your understanding is right,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just simply use [**`valueGetter`**](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-getters/) method of the Ag-grid.

We can render the value for the particular column based on it's field value. Please try to change your code something like below,

```
 columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: 'Button Col 1',
      cellRenderer: 'buttonRenderer',
      valueGetter: (params) => this.displayColumnLabel(params.data.fieldName)
      cellRendererParams: {
        onClick: this.onBtnClick1.bind(this),
        label: 'Click 1'
      }
    },
   ...
   ];

  displayColumnLabel(fieldValue) {
    if(fieldValue) {
      return fieldValue; // do something you want to do with value (modifications)
    }
    return 'some default text or value';
  }
```

Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if I get your question right but you can change the ButtonRenderComponent to something like this:

```
<button type="button" (click)="onClick($event)">{{params.data.make}}</button>
```

Comment: thank you for your response, and your time. But i am using columndefs and using this columndefs to populate the ag-grid no where in my code i have this button element. this is done internally by the angular-ag-grid-button renderer .so i dont think this would work

Comment: So you don't have button-rendered.component.ts in your project?

Comment: Oh I found it, sorry about that yes it is there, but i am using the same for other buttons as well, i dont want to display {{params.data.make}} in all fields instead only the make field.
so i am using the same button for model, but that should be displaying model field.

Answer (score 1):

```
button-rendered.component.ts
this.label = this.params.value|| null;
```

```
app.component.ts

columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: 'Button Col 1',
      cellRenderer: 'buttonRenderer',
      field: 'make',
      cellRendererParams: {
        onClick: this.onBtnClick1.bind(this),
        label: 'Click 1'
      }
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Button Col 2',
      cellRenderer: 'buttonRenderer',
      field: 'model',
      cellRendererParams: {
        onClick: this.onBtnClick2.bind(this),
        label: 'Click 2'
      }
    },
    { headerName: 'Model', field: 'model' },
    { headerName: 'Price', field: 'price' }
  ];
```

you can also access the data for a row in the `params.data` in the renderer and write logic to show label based on different field values in that row

Comment: thank you for your response, and your time, i think this may be getting closer to the solution. So are you implying i can writing something like this 


     `headerName: 'Button Col 2',
      cellRenderer: 'buttonRenderer',
      field: 'model',
      cellRendererParams: {
        onClick: this.onBtnClick2.bind(this),
        -------------------------------------------------> label: this.Params.value`
(question but how do i access param data here)

Answer (score 1):

you need to update the logic in your button renderer to render the label based on `params.data` rather than getting hardcoded value from `colDefs`.

In your `button-renderer.component.ts` change `lable` logic like below

```
 agInit(params): void {
    this.params = params;
    debugger;
    this.label = params.data.make || null; // here use any property from params.data or write custom logic to populate label.
  }
```

[stackblitz demo](https://angular-ag-grid-button-renderer-sxkqwe.stackblitz.io)

Comment: thank you for your response, and your time. this helped me. Can i know the name of column inside agInit? for example i have two columns to make have these buttons for and each need their own label.

Comment: `params.colDef` will give you all detail about column for which the button is getting rendered.

Comment: thank you for your response, and your time. this helped me.